# Can I tell the last website someone visited before my site?

Tags: javascript, web

Let's say someone clicks a link for my blog acme.com.

Is it possible to determine the source that they came from? By source I mean, can I tell whether they clicked on this link from Facebook or Google or another blog?

This is operating under the assumption that they had to enter my site from clicking a link.

I'm also assuming that I don't have any trackers on this user and it is their first time visiting my website. And I don't have access to Google Analytics.

Comment: there is nothing stopping you adding your own parameters to your links `?site=fb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer). It is meant precisely for this case.

Answer (score 0):

**referer** in the **headers**, but i would say other than that no.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log(document.referrer);
```